# Typescript, object extends from interface and get its type

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Hewan {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const createKucing = (name: string, age: number) => (
  {
    type: 'kucing' as const,
    name,
    age,
    miaw: true,
  } as ({} extends Hewan)
);

type Kucing = ReturnType<typeof createKucing>;

const isKucing = (x: unknown): x is Kucing => (x as Kucing).type === 'kucing';
```

I want to make an object constractor `createKucing` and also the interface of `Kucing` which is ReturnType of createKucing itself. So `Kucing` interface will change dynamically as soon as I change the constructor.

But I want the `createKucing` is extends from `Hewan`. So `Hewan` interface is kind of abstraction for `Kucing`. So, the `type`, `name`, and `age` is required when I make a constructor, but also I want to still can add property on it like `miaw`. Is that possible? I tried with assertion extends but it shows an error.

> '?' expected.

I expect `Kucing` to have `miaw` property as I made it on constructor, but I want to the constructor is inherit from `Hewan`. Is that possible?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Hewan {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Kucing extends Hewan {
  type: 'kucing';
  miaw: boolean;
}

const createKucing = (name: string, age: number): Kucing => (...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIQO5xMg3gKGWTAE8AHCALmQGcwpQBzAbkORDgFsrb6nWicRjxABXTgCNorAL758oSLEQoA0qIRNkEAB6QQAExppM2PG1IVqAcgDWGptYHJOwOBmoSA9l4A2EbFl5BC8QOmQEKADIdU0QRmQAXmQACg5uajoGeIAaZCERcSkoAEpqWK1EgD5UtgIiIkseOwd463zjELCwHLYidIhehvzhIYbXd2p6UUG2ORLWfC7w4BoK+KTUnWpREFsQLwwQMuQdZFXkdYTqrY7L1sYSgDompMTklrjGJ2DQ8NtNpFohArilrANrHkAIwADgWQA)

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Hewan {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  [index:string]:any;
}
```

Comment: thx, that's works. but, the Kucing is now equal as Hewan, and doesn't have miaw property on it.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible.